# Validate Xml with XSd without using XSD physical path

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am validating XML with XSD in **C#**.
 Following is the code

```
 var test = "C:/Temp/xmlconnector5.0.xsd";
 var settings = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
 settings.Schemas.Add(null, test);
 settings.Schemas.Compile();
 settings.ValidationType = System.Xml.ValidationType.Schema;
 var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlDoc.InnerXml), settings);
 while (reader.Read())
 {
 }
```

The  above code is working fine. But is it  possible to not to use **physical path of XSD**.

**I don't want to use Path of XSD**, instead want to use XSD itself which I have added into project as Add Exisitng item.

Note:- I have crated a class from XSD and using it as my Model.

Comment: When you post code, please say what language it is in. Not everyone will recognize this as VB, and those that do might waste 10 seconds working it out.

Comment: I have updated the language.. It is C#